# Setup htaccess not to redirect when hit from main site

Tags: .htaccess

I'm not even sure how to ask this correctly so if I am duplicating a question I apologize.  How do I use my htaccess file to only redirect when someone is coming in on something other than the main site name?

Example: 
I do not want redirect on www.examplesite.com
I do want to redirect on www.examplesite.com/page.php

Comment: Where do you want to redirect to?

Comment: I was over-complicating things.  Turns out I didn't need a redirect after all.  Thank you for the question and for everyone who kicked out a response.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

Perform a redirection with `.htaccess`

The easiest and simplest way of redirecting with `.htaccess` is to use the Apache module `mod_alias` and its command `Redirect`. Here’s is how to make a temporary redirection with htaccess:

`Redirect /page.php http://www.examplesite.com/go_to_this_page.php`

Is this along the lines of what you're asking? If so, I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

The Structure : redirect accessed-file URL-to-go-to

The code :

`Redirect 301 / http://www.examplesite.com/page.php`